# Enable the 'table of contents'-sidepane in Document Viewer

Tags: pdf

I remember having a sidepane with the table of contents in a specific PDF file. I played around with the program and now it is closed. I can't find a way to reopen the above mentioned sidepane. Is there a hotkey for that or what is the name of the option?

With 'Document Viewer' I refer to the Ubuntu standard pdf application.

Comment: You mean pressing F9?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Oh, yes indeed. My problem was that you can let the sidepane show different things. I had it set to 'Thumbnails', wich just showed the pictures of the pages. I switched that to 'Outline' and now I got my table of contents. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described by '@guillermo chamorro' in the comments: when I press F9 the sidepanel pops up. It can show different things, that are selectable in the dropdown menue on top. To view the table of contents of a document that drop down needs to be set to the 'Outline' setting.

Comment: How do you "set to the 'Outline' setting."?

Comment: nm found it. bottom left of window after the sidepanel pops up. 4 icons visible at the bottom of the sidepanel showing the thumbnails. (not the dropdown menu on top right)